# Android RecyclerView: get the previous item in paginated list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that lists messages, now as you know messages tend to become large overtime, so I implemeted pagination.

Now I know that I can get the previous item only if position is positive like this:

```
     public void getItemViewType(int position){
      //get any item at position
      Message message = mylist.get(position);

      //get the previous item
      if(position > 0){
       Message message = mylist.get(position - 1);
      } 

     }
```

But the above works only if position > 0. What do I do when position is 0?

How do I know the previous item of the very first message in my list? Because there might be messages that will come after pagination.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when your position is 0 get the first message:

```
Message message = mylist.get(position > 0 ? position - 1 : 0);
```

Comment: This is not the question. My question is how do I get the previous item of the the item at position 0?

Comment: in your adapter the position of the first visible item is 0 so call getLayoutPosition(); to get the position of each message while pagination